# Adding a watchlist functionality for JPA Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Post entity and a User entity  (User can create many posts/advertisements), i'm trying to add a watchlist functionality so that a user can select any post and it would be watchlisted (Allowing them to kind of save a post for future reference).

I created a new entity called WatchlistPost, which contains a reference to both the User and the Post entities, and I can save a watchlisted post but I'd like to only allow a user to watchlist a particular post once (atm a user can watchlist multiple posts even if the post is the same / has the same post id).

A user should be able to watchlist multiple Posts, but not the same post multiple times.

[image: A user can watchlist the same post multiple times]

---

This is my Post Entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Post {

    private long EXPIRATION_TIME_DAYS = 14;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Required")
    @Size(min=20, message = "Minimum of 20 characters")
    @Size(max=100, message = "Maximum of 100 characters")
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String title;

    @NotBlank(message = "Required")
    @Size(min = 50, message = "Minimum of 50 characters")
    @Size(max = 2000, message = "Maximum of 2000 characters")
    @Column(length = 2000)
    private String description;

    // Removed other fields

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

}
```

---

**My User Entity**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Required")
    private String fullName;

    // Removed other fields


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();



}
```

---

**Watchlist Post Entity**

```
package com.carspot.app.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="watchlist_post")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class WatchlistPost {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Post post;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;
}
```

---

**MySQL DDL for Watchlist table**
[image: Watchlist table DDL]

---

**Service method to add a Watchlist Post**

```
    @Override
    public void addToWatchlist(Long postId, String emailAddress) {
        User user = userRepository.findUserByEmailAddress(emailAddress);

        // findPostById(id) - finds post by id, or throws Exception if post doesn't exist
        Post post = findPostById(postId);

        WatchlistPost watchlistPost = new WatchlistPost();
        watchlistPost.setPost(post);
        watchlistPost.setUser(user);

        postWatchlistRepository.save(watchlistPost);

    }
```

---

**Controller method**

```
    @PostMapping("api/post/watchlist/{postId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addToWatchList(@PathVariable Long postId, Principal principal) {
        postService.addToWatchlist(postId, principal.getName());
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Post added to watchlist", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: From `WatchlistPost` remove the `Long id` column and place `@Id` on both relationships. That way you ensure that each id pair is unique

Comment: Your model (slightly) doesn't match your requirements/description ..yes, you need to "constraint" user/post somehow...i recommend: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ and https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: You have to change your database, the three fields should be unique to not allow repeated rows. Besides that, in your model, the three attributes should have the `@Id` annotation too

Comment: IMHO, there is a problem with the database schema/mapping. You do not need to map the WATCHLISTPOST table to a Java entity. The WATCHLISTPOST is M:N relationship type between USER and POST, with no own attributes.

Comment: @maxdesimone thanks for the reply, I tried creating a M:N relation between User and Post, I am now able to watchlist a post fine, but the issue is that I can't watchlist more than one post per user id, when I watchlist another post, the entry gets updated in the DB with that post id, instead of adding it, which makes sense because of the user id pk.